# How can i access Remote oracle Database in my java project via LAN, Oracle is not installed in my machine

Tags: java, oracle10g, ojdbc

I want to access a database in my java project though LAN, the oracle database is installed in another machine i want to fetch all the data in my java project & i don't have installed oracle in my machine?

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/urls.htm#JJDBC28267)?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, it is possible without installing an Oracle client.
You need to get the oracle jdbc **thin** driver
See : http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC#Thin_driver

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

public class Test {


    public static void main(String args[])
     throws Exception{


        System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", "C:/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/NETWORK/ADMIN");


        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        System.out.println("Successfully Installed drivers");


        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@100.100.103.61:1521/orcl","scott", "tiger");


        System.out.println("Goodddddd");

        Statement st  = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from  dept ");

        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " " + rs.getString(2) + " " +rs.getString(3));    
        }}}
```

Make sure you first check your database is being ping in your system.